Issue with Sidekiq and Redis in Production on Rails 7.0.8.1
I'm experiencing issues configuring Sidekiq in my production environment. The application is a Rails 7.0.8.1 running on an Ubuntu 22.04 server, and the installed Redis version is 7.2.5. However, when starting Sidekiq, it tries to connect to an older version of Redis (6.0.16), causing it to fail.
Environment Setup
Systemd Service File (/etc/systemd/system/sidekiq.service):
[Unit]
Description=Sidekiq
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/lipepay/current
ExecStart=/home/deploy/start_sidekiq.sh
User=deploy
Group=deploy
UMask=0002
RestartSec=15
Restart=always
Environment=REDIS_URL=redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Startup Script (/home/deploy/start_sidekiq.sh):
#!/bin/bash
# File: /home/deploy/start_sidekiq.sh

# Load Ruby version manager environment
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

# Set REDIS_URL
export REDIS_URL=redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0

# Navigate to application directory
cd /home/deploy/lipepay/current

# Start Sidekiq
exec /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq -e production

Sidekiq Initializer (config/initializers/sidekiq.rb):
require 'sidekiq/cron'

if Rails.env.production?
  schedule_file = "config/schedule.yml"
  
  if File.exist?(schedule_file) && Sidekiq.server?
    yaml_jobs = YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
    existing_jobs = Sidekiq::Cron::Job.all.map(&:name)
    
    yaml_jobs.each do |name, details|
      unless existing_jobs.include?(name)
        Sidekiq::Cron::Job.create(name: name, cron: details['cron'], class: details['class'])
      end
    end
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
  end
end

Error Logs
Here is the output from journalctl -u sidekiq:
Jun 26 17:34:27 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[348225]: You are connecting to Redis 6.0.16, Sidekiq requires Redis 6.2.0 or greater
Jun 26 17:34:27 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[348225]: /home/deploy/lipepay/shared/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/sidekiq-7.1.1/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:184:in `verify_sufficient_redis_version'

Steps Taken
Check Redis Version:
redis-server --version
# Output: Redis server v=7.2.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.3.0 bits=64 build=d2f534f69a26fea

Verify Connection in Rails Console:
redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDIS_URL'])
puts redis.info["redis_version"]
# Output: 7.2.5

Check Dependencies in Gemfile.lock:
grep sidekiq Gemfile.lock
# Output:
# sidekiq (7.1.1)
# sidekiq-cron (1.10.1)

Also sidekiq seems to be correctly configured:
sudo systemctl status sidekiq:
● sidekiq.service - Sidekiq
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sidekiq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-06-27 20:42:21 UTC; 8min ago
   Main PID: 805007 (ruby)
      Tasks: 11 (limit: 2252)
     Memory: 171.8M
        CPU: 3.620s
     CGroup: /system.slice/sidekiq.service
             └─805007 "sidekiq 7.1.1 lipepay [0 of 5 busy]" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "">

Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.015Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for mor>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.015Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Sidekiq 7.1.1 connecting to Re>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.019Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Cron Jobs - added job with nam>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.021Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Cron Jobs - added job with nam>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.023Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Cron Jobs - added job with nam>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.025Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Cron Jobs - added job with nam>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.027Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Cron Jobs - added job with nam>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.029Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Cron Jobs - added job with nam>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.030Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Cron Jobs - added job with nam>
Jun 27 20:42:24 ubuntu-2gb-hil-1 start_sidekiq.sh[805007]: 2024-06-27T20:42:24.032Z pid=805007 tid=hd1v INFO: Cron Jobs - added job with nam>
lines 1-20/20 (END)


This issue was solved after running this commands:
redis-cli flushall
rm -rf tmp/cache

And giving the correct permissions:
chmod +x /home/deploy/start_sidekiq.sh

